# To run once again mkfs.xfs quickly

Tags: filesystems, xfs

I run

```
mkfs.xfs -f -L /partitionname -d agcount=64 -l size=128m,version=2 /dev/sdb1
```

but noticed that enough without Label with UUID, while the old when RHEL used partition labels, as discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/a/367077/1944):

```
mkfs.xfs -f -d agcount=64 -l size=128m,version=2 /dev/sdb1
```

to just reset the name. 
However, there can be a better way to do this.

How can you run once again the mkfs.xfs quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are looking for.

Does `xfs_admin` suit your purpose here ?

```
NAME
       xfs_admin - change parameters of an XFS filesystem

SYNOPSIS
       xfs_admin [ -eflpu ] [ -c 0|1 ] [ -L label ] [ -U uuid ] device
       xfs_admin -V

DESCRIPTION
       xfs_admin  uses the xfs_db(8) command to modify various parameters of a
       filesystem.
```

Comment: Yes, I believe the `-L` option to `xfs_admin` should be what's needed to change the filesystem label (which I think is what is being asked).

Comment: Answer in mjturner's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in mjturner's comment. Run `xfs_admin` with the parameter `-L`.